# Laravel 5.4 SMTP error "send AUTH command first"

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, laravel-5.4

I'm getting the following error trying to send mail from localhost using smtp:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "503", with message "503 5.5.4
>   Error: send AUTH command first. "

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.yandex.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=robot@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=11111111
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM=robot@domain.com
MAIL_NAME=MY.NAME
```

**config/mail.php**

```
 <?php
    return [
        'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.yandex.com'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
        'from' => [
            'address' => 'robot@domain.com',
            'name' => 'MY.NAME',
        ],
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
        'username' => env('robot@domain.com'),
        'password' => env('11111111'),
        'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    ];
```

Tried: changing ports, encryption, clearing cache, restarting server in all possible combinations. :)
As I see it there's one more parameter I need to pass to the mailer library. Some thing like

```
auth_mode=login_first
```

Can this be done through laravel settings?

Comment: You may change to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null`. But then I got `Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message ""`
Also for development consider using [nice and free mail catcher](https://mailtrap.io/). And don't forget to clear config cache `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: I tried not setting the encryption at all, but it didn't help. Also, I think that this particular smtp server requires ssl. Over the last few hours I've tried mailgun, mandrill, sparkpost and was getting only more errors. This wasn't supposed to be that difficult, right? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting my working settings. You've got to check how laravel `env` helper function is used in your config file. Also when using smtp.yandex.com auth email and form email must match.

[Laravel Docs for env()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-env)

> The env function gets the value of an environment variable or returns a default value:
>
> $env = env('APP_ENV');
>
> // Return a default value if the variable doesn't exist...
>
> $env = env('APP_ENV', 'production');

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.yandex.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=robot@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=123123123
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM=robot@mydomain.com
MAIL_NAME=MY.NAME
```

**config/mail.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.yandex.com'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
    'from' => [
        'address' =>  env('MAIL_FROM','robot@mydomain.com'),
        'name' =>  env('MAIL_NAME','MY.NAME'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','robot@mydomain.com'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','123123123'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
];
```

**Controller function**

```
public function testmail()
{
    $user =  Auth::user();
    $pathToLogo = config('app.url').'/images/logo/logo_250.png';
    Mail::send('emails.testmail', array('user' => $user, 'pathToLogo' => $pathToLogo), function($message) use ($user)
        {
          $message->to($user->email);
          $message->subject('Test message');
        });
    return redirect()->route('home')->with('message','Test message sent.');
}
```